# Comparing array of objects and add, update, or remove based on property

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, object

I'm trying to compare the current state of selected options against an incoming state of options. The incoming state will have property `selected` which is a boolean.

What I'm trying to accomplish is this: If an item in the `incomingOptions` has `selected: true`, update the same item in `currentState` or add it to the current state if it doesn't exist. If `selected: false`, the item should not be returned in the new state.

```
const currentState = {
  products: [
    {
      optionid: 808541,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808542,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808543,
      quantity: 6
    },
    {
      optionid: 808546,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808547,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808548,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808549,
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      optionid: 808550,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808551,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808552,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808553,
      quantity: 7
    }
  ]
};
```

```
const incomingOptions = [
  {
    id: 808539, // this item is new
    selected: true,
    quantity: 5
  },
  {
    id: 808540, // this item is new
    selected: true,
    quantity: 5
  },
  {
    id: 808541, // this item exists in current state, but is now false
    selected: false,
    quantity: 5
  },
  {
    id: 808542, // this item exists in current state, but the quantity is now 10
    selected: true,
    quantity: 10
  },
  {
    id: 808543,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 808544,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 808545,
    selected: false
  }
];
```

The final state I'm after is this:

```
products: [
    {
       "optionid": 808542,
       "quantity": 10
    },
    {
        "optionid": 808546,
        "quantity": 7
    },
    {
        "optionid": 808547,
        "quantity": 7
    },
    {
        "optionid": 808548,
        "quantity": 7
    },
    {
        "optionid": 808549,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "optionid": 808550,
        "quantity": 7
    },
    {
        "optionid": 808551,
        "quantity": 7
    },
    {
        "optionid": 808552,
        "quantity": 7
    },
    {
        "optionid": 808553,
        "quantity": 7
    },
    {
        "optionid": 808539,
        "quantity": 5
    },
    {
        "optionid": 808540,
        "quantity": 5
    }
]
```

I've tried using `reduce` with a combination of `findIndex`, but I'm finding that I'm needing to loop things over several times and it feels really inefficient.

Forgot my first pass, which updates the current items, but not any new items:

```
const updatedState = state.products.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const option = currentOptions.find((opt) => opt.id === curr.optionid);
  if (option) {
    return option.selected
      ? 
        [
          ...acc,
          {
            ...curr,
            quantity: option.quantity
          }
        ]
      : acc;
  }
  return [...acc, curr];
}, []);
```

Comment: Either use reduce and findIndex (nothing wrong with it), or convert your array to an Object for easier manipulation, where the key will be the product ID - if.... the products are indeed unique in the array anyways. Where's your code? You're asking this question to get an *elegant* solution to something working? Try to provide some code anyways.

Comment: Can happen in the products array to have **more than one product with the same ID?** If that's the case, the logic complexity rises drastically. If the answer is no - than perhaps converting that array to an object would be a smart move

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thought I included what was working which is updated a current state item. Yes, each product ID is unique. What would converting it to an object do for me?

Comment: @hybrid9 you could do direct lookup istead of doing an iteration with find. say if your incoming option would look something like `{808539:{ id: 808539, selected: true, quantity: 5 }....}`  then `const option = incoming[curr.optionid]`

Comment: @cmgchess So instead of an array of objects an object of objects with the key being the id?

Comment: yeah but what you already have is also fine i guess to add the new ones you can do something like `const pidSet = new Set(products.map(x => x.optionid))` and `const withNew = incomingOptions.reduce((acc, curr) =>  !pidSet.has(curr.id) && curr.selected ? [...acc,{optionid:curr.id,quantity:curr.quantity}]: acc,updatedState)`

Comment: @cmgchess I gave that a shot, but what ends up happening is an item that already exists isn't removed if selected is false. I'll keep hacking on it - appreciate your input.

Comment: Hmm Did you manage it I couldn't test properly

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to slightly modify the input data:

```js
const currentState = {
  products: [
    {
      optionid: 808541,
      quantity: 7
    },
```

— it can be simplified to:

```js
const currentState = {
  808541: 7,
```

Given the above you can just use a simple, readable, easily debuggable `forEach` like:

```js
const currentState = {
  808541: 7, 808542: 7, 808543: 6,
  808546: 7, 808547: 7, 808548: 7,
  808549: 1, 808550: 7, 808551: 7,
  808552: 7, 808553: 7,
};

const incomingOptions = [
  {id: 808539, selected: true, quantity: 5},
  {id: 808540, selected: true, quantity: 5},
  {id: 808541, selected: false, quantity: 5},
  {id: 808542, selected: true, quantity: 10},
  {id: 808543, selected: false},
  {id: 808544, selected: false},
  {id: 808545, selected: false}
];

const res = {...currentState}; // Shallow clone

incomingOptions.forEach((opt) => {
  if (opt.selected) res[opt.id] = opt.quantity;
  else delete res[opt.id];
});

console.log(res);
```

Readable, reasonable, and developer friendly.
If you really want to stick to something more compact (no reason to), you can always do:

```js
incomingOptions.forEach(opt => 
  opt.selected ? res[opt.id] = opt.quantity : delete res[opt.id]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```js
const currentState = {
  products: [
    {
      optionid: 808541,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808542,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808543,
      quantity: 6
    },
    {
      optionid: 808546,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808547,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808548,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808549,
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      optionid: 808550,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808551,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808552,
      quantity: 7
    },
    {
      optionid: 808553,
      quantity: 7
    }
  ]
};

const incomingOptions = [
  {
    id: 808539, // this item is new
    selected: true,
    quantity: 5
  },
  {
    id: 808540, // this item is new
    selected: true,
    quantity: 5
  },
  {
    id: 808541, // this item exists in current state, but is now false
    selected: false,
    quantity: 5
  },
  {
    id: 808542, // this item exists in current state, but the quantity is now 10
    selected: true,
    quantity: 10
  },
  {
    id: 808543,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 808544,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 808545,
    selected: false
  }
];

const removeItems = incomingOptions.filter(item => !item.selected).map(item => item.id);

const filterCurrent = currentState.products.filter(item => removeItems.includes(item.optionid) === false);
const filterIncomming = incomingOptions.filter(item => item.selected);

const result = {};

filterCurrent.forEach(({ optionid, quantity }) => {
  const find = filterIncomming.find(value => value.id === optionid);
  result[optionid] = find ? { optionid, quantity: find.quantity } : { optionid, quantity };
});

filterIncomming.forEach(item => {
  result[item.id] ??= { optionid: item.id, quantity: item.quantity };
})



console.log({products: Object.values(result)});
```